# SQL dynamic command text

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, sqlcommand

I've been getting a lot of useful help on loops. however, I'm finding each situation is different when dealing with different objects. I have run into a situation where I want to dynamically use different SQL command strings.

Basically, I need help to turn:

```
SqlCommand(queryString1, connection)
```

into something like:

```
SqlCommand(queryString(i), connection)
```

I need to loop `queryString1` - `queryString10`

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString1, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i).Text() = reader("EMPLOYEE")
        End While
        reader.Close()
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot create an array (or list) of the query strings? Also, `"LblStckRnk" & i` should be `"LblStckRnk" & i.ToString()` - please consider using [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Comment: @Andrew Morton, everything is good in the loop except:SqlCommand("queryString" & i, connection). when i run that code, I get an error:Could not find stored procedure 'queryString1'. and im assuming becuase its actually querying "queryString1" rather than the string that was stored for that command. I just want to combine queryString and (i) so i can get to all my other SQL strings.

Comment: If your query strings are in an array named `queryString` then it would be `SqlCommand(queryString(i), connection)`.

Comment: oops sorry, they are not. only becuase all the queries are all different.

Comment: @Andrew Morton, when I set the array to (Dim queryString(10) As String) and SqlCommand(queryString(i), connection) I get the error: "ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized"

Comment: You have to put the strings in the array. Do you need assistance doing that?

Comment: @Andrew Morton, yeah, could you show me?

Comment: @Joseph.Scott.Garza Even if all the queries are different, they're still all strings, yes? In which case there is no problem putting them in the same array so long as you keep the query for `LblStckRnk1` lined up with `queryString(1)`. Beware of the zero-indexing on arrays though.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [VB.NET Array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-vbnet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string(10) like this :

```
 Dim queryString(9) As String
 queryString(0) = "queryString1"
 queryString(1) = "queryString2"
 queryString(2) = "queryString3"
 queryString(3) = "queryString4"
 queryString(4) = "queryString5"
 queryString(5) = "queryString6"
 queryString(6) = "queryString7"
 queryString(7) = "queryString8"
 queryString(8) = "queryString9"
 queryString(9) = "queryString10"

 Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString(I), connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i+1).Text() = reader("EMPLOYEE")
    End While
    reader.Close()

    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Umm.. `Dim queryString(9) As String` ;)

Comment: @Al-3sli, it seems to be working but I'm getting an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for this part: " Controls.Item("LblStckRnk" & i).Text() = reader("EMPLOYEE")"

Comment: Also, as an aside, I'd recommend putting the `Using connection...` outside the for-loop unless you have a particular reason you need to open/close a connection each time.